# BASH how do I check if numeric permissions passed as argument are a valid combination?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a script that reads a set of numeric file permissions as argument it works like this:

$ bash script 755

This will give 755 permissions to some file on the disk. I want to know how to check if the number passed as parameter contains a valid set of permissions. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: All solutions need to take into account linux permissions are `4-octal` bytes not the `3` shown. You have the *sticky-bit* and `Setuid` and `Setgid`.

Comment: Oops!  You forgot to include any code in your question!  We're happy to help you learn your craft, but your own work so far *must* be the starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

> `[0-7]{3}`

https://regex101.com/r/bQ8jB6/1

---

if you prefer:

> `^[0-7]{3}$`

https://regex101.com/r/bQ8jB6/2

Comment: that also matches 7778

Comment: Only with the 777, in 7778; it's not a full match; if you prefer: https://regex101.com/r/bQ8jB6/2
^[0-7]{3}$

Comment: @siete.sh Whether or not `[0-7]{3}` would match 7778 depends on what program is actually doing the matching. You can't really give an answer involving regular expressions without saying how to use it.

Comment: Seems like the question is about how to use regex in bash test.

Comment: This is a good answer, I need to validate the input before actually processing the argument. Example to distinguish the first argument is a valid chmod  and I dont care whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

chmod returns an error code and visible error text to the shell if you pass chmod invalid permissions, e.g.,

```
> chmod 788 some/file
chmod: Invalid file mode: 788
```

so

```
chmod $1 some/file || <handle the error>
```

in your script will either chmod successfully, or else handle the error however you like.

Or, more verbosely:

```
chmod $1 some/file
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    <handle the error>
fi
```

If, for some unexplained reason you, prefer a pure regex answer before attempting to chmod, a modified version of @siete.sh's will work, e.g.,

```
[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-7]{3}$ ]] && chmod $1 some/file
```

or, since 1 to 5 digits are all valid arguments to chmod:

```
[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-7]{1,5}$ ]] && chmod $1 some/file
```

Comment: What version of `chmod` accepts a 5-digit octal number as a valid mode?

Comment: In my opinion, ´chmod $1 some/file || exit´ is a little drastic;
you can try ´chmod $1 some/file´, and then, you can find the return value of the last executed command in ´$?´ variable; only zero means success.
If ´$?´ is equals to zero ... else ...